# Github Commit hooks for server integration into cloud9

Tags: version-control, github, cloud9-ide

I work for a small agency that works mainly with php, and we were searching for a simple form of version control. I came across cloud9, and it seemed perfect, but I found no way to integrate it with our servers.

However, cloud9 does integrate seamlessly with github, which made me think is there a way to integrate github with my server. Now I'm under the impression that you can use a 'post_commit' hook in svn to ftp a file to a server when a commit is made. Is there a feature similar to these that I can use with a github repository to automatically send a file to a server when a commit is made? Or is there any software I can install on my server to listen for any changes in a github repository to update itself when any changed are made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub offers [post receive hooks](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/), which can be used to do what you want. Whenever you push to GitHub a POST request to a pre configured URL is sent. The body of the POST message contains a JSON structure with all the information about the push and the commits involved.